# First Fold Performing Worse Than Other Folds in Cross Validation

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, model-evaluation

I have done a 80:20 split on my data. On my training data, I am getting 88% accuracy, but I wanted to perform cross validation on my training set. Now my accuracy is being reduced to 80%, which is a problem, since on my testing data, I am achieving 84% accuracy. So it makes my training accuracy< testing accuracy. And only the first fold of cross-validation has low performance, the others are doing quite well. I am not able to understand these discrepancies.

```
#Testing without CV
nn_class = MLPClassifier()
nn_class.fit(x_train,y_train)
y_training = nn_class.predict(x_train)
performance(y_train,y_training)

cv_results = cross_validate(nn_class, x_train, y_train, cv=5, scoring=scoring)
cross_validate_results(cv_results)
```

[image]

cv_results is just a function that returns the mean performance from all folds.

```
print("Precision: ",cv_results['test_prec'])
print("Recall: ", cv_results['test_recall'])
print("ROC-AUC: ", cv_results['test_auc'])
print("Specificity: ", cv_results['test_specificity'])
print("Matthew's Correlation Coefficient", cv_results['test_mcc'])
print("F1:  ",cv_results['test_f1'])
print("TN: ",np.round(cv_results['test_tn']))
print("TP: ",np.round(cv_results['test_tp']))
print("FN: ",np.round(cv_results['test_fn']))
print("FP: ",np.round(cv_results['test_fp']))
```

Performance on Testing Set:

```
nn_class.fit(x_train,y_train)
y_pred = nn_class.predict(x_test_k_best)
print(performance(y_test,y_pred))
```

[image]

Comment: What makes you think there is something wrong here?  Due to the nature of probability, wouldn't you expect some variance when measuring accuracy on different inputs?  Do you shuffle your training data before running on it?  (if not, maybe the data has some structure and the first part of it contains data distributed differently than the data in the rest of it)

Comment: [Please don't shout.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3184/1352)

Answer (score 2):

Cross-validation calculates accuracy metrics on data that hasn't been seen by the model. It essentially breaks your training data into multiple train and test sets and reports the performance on the test portion. In that way, the CV accuracy is similar to test accuracy, not training accuracy. The performance of the model will vary based on the training and test set, so the fact that the estimated cross-validation accuracy might be 4% lower than the test accuracy is not surprising on its own. It is also not surprising that different folds in the CV results have different accuracies. The goal of CV is to get a sample of accuracies, in your case five. You can then average them to get a more stable estimate of the out of sample performance, and you can calculate the standard error of the five estimates to create a sort of confidence interval.

Unless you're using the CV results to tune or change the model in some way, there is no reason to perform it and then immediately evaluate the accuracy on the test set. You'd be better off performing CV on the entire dataset to estimate test performance.

Comment: +1. Also known as "out of bag error". Welcome to CrossValidated!